# Delphi checkboxlist and copy file with progress

Tags: delphi

Followed this [FileCopyProgress](http://www.delphigeist.com/2009/09/how-to-copy-file-and-display-its.html) working for single files, need it to work with mutiple
Have a checboxlist that populates files from a directory <- works fine
can copy a single file no problem, but need to copy each file that is selected

Code to populate checkbox list

```
procedure ListFileDir(Ext: string;Path: string; FileList: TStrings);
var
SR: TSearchRec;
begin
 if FindFirst(Path + Ext, faAnyFile, SR) = 0 then
 begin
  repeat
   FileList.Add(UpperCase(SR.Name));
   until FindNext(SR) <> 0;
   FindClose(SR);
   end;
end;
```

Code to check if the Checkbox is selected

```
{ checkboxes }
for i := 0 to cblLogs.Items.Count - 1 do
if cblLogs.Checked[i] then
  s := s + cblLogs.Items[i];
```

[image: Problem]

Comment: What is the problem? You know how to fill the list and you know how to get the checked items. Each time you have a checked item start the copy ... or fill a list/array and work on this list/array afterwards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are adding all of the names to a single string. That won't work. You need to do something like this:

```
{ checkboxes }
for i := 0 to cblLogs.Items.Count - 1 do
if cblLogs.Checked[i] then
  TurboFileCopy(cblLogs.Items[i], 'X:\' + cblLogs.Items[i], nil);
```

Or alternatively you could build up a stringlist and use that later on with something like this:

```
filesToCopy := TStringList.Create;

...

for i := 0 to cblLogs.Items.Count - 1 do
if cblLogs.Checked[i] then
  filesToCopy.Add(cblLogs.Items[i]);

...

for i := 0 to filesToCopy.Count - 1 do
  TurboFileCopy(filesToCopy[i], BuildTargetFileName(filesToCopy[i]), nil);
```

This will process each file individually.